# Tagging foreign language films

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there a system for tagging foreign language films (i.e., languages other than English)? I would personally like to follow questions on all Korean and Japanese films and there does not appear to be any way to do this currently. I have also had language tags removed from my questions in the past.

**Updates:**

- In other words, I'd like to see all Japanese movies like Rashomon, Ikiru, etc., tagged either with [japan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan) or [japanese](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese). The same would happen for all Korean, French, Spanish, Thai, and other movies.
- I see now that there *is* a [japanese-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-movie) tag.
- There is also a [french](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) tag.

Comment: May this discussion help http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/977/foreign-non-us-movie-name-tag-should-be-of-original-title-or-english-dubbed-ti

Comment: @AnkitSharma My language tags have been removed in some questions. You don't see a _Korean_ tag for questions on [Oldboy](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldboy), do you? Presumably there is some reason for this.

Comment: @druciferre Please check this thread out.

Comment: Already checked. :)

Comment: In general i was in favor of tags like Japanese and Bollywood to bunch them up together. But community is MOSTLY against it till its an ID.

Comment: Nopes.....i only have one account....but What made you think that

Comment: ohh....i thought it addressed to me, doesn't noticed druciferre's name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with these sort of tags is that they describe the movie or tv show, but they don't describe what the **question** is about, and that's ultimately what the tags are for, to let us know in advance what the question pertains to.  We currently do not have a system to categorize tags.

Comment: Thank you. In that case, how do "action", "thriller", "anime" or "bollywood" satisfy that criterion?

Comment: they don't unless they're on identification questions (the one exception for this rule).  I'm cleaning up those tags.

Comment: tagging @coleopterist so you get my response

Comment: @coleopterist or the question is specifically asking about that subject.  for instance: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12467/what-is-first-bollywood-film-having-sequel-prequel

Comment: Thanks. So I guess that it's functionally impossible for me to be alerted to questions on Korean and Japanese films.

Comment: Re: tags relevant to the question: Yes I suppose that questions on the history of Bollywood satisfy this requirement. But from what I can tell, that is now how it is primarily used. Similarly, most [ridley-scott] questions don't have anything to do with him in particular. In the case of [anime], it's probably more than most :|

Comment: @coleopterist yeah our tagging system is a bit of a mess at the moment.  but yeah, they're really supposed to be relevant to the question itself, not just tangential information.

Comment: @coleopterist Oh yeah, the habit of putting director names in tags is something that waits for a big meta discussion for a long time already. Yet I'm too lazy to start it myself either. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree so much with this approach. First of all because of *DForck42*'s argument, which is the same reason why the `action` tag is discouraged on a question about *Mission Impossible*.

And furthermore we would have to use this on all questions, tagging *"non-foreign language movies"* (from the point of view of this question) as `english`. The reason this site's language is English is not because it is mainly about English language movies or because the community is centered around English native speakers, but because the community is *international* and *multilingual* (a case for which English has established itself as lingua franca). English is the language of this site, not of the topic discussed on this site. Therefore English language movies theoretically don't have a special position among the movies discussed on this site (they practically have, because those are the ones most people have seen and can discuss about).

And even more than that, the language in which a movie was produced doesn't say much about the movie at all (if it can even be decided clearly, see *The Good, The Bad and The Ugly*). What you may be after are the countries or, much more important, the cultures which the movies were produced in. But this cannot be decided that easily either. And who then decides that Korean movies are more worth to mention their origin than Hollywood movies or other U.S. movies or other English movies or movies produced in Romania, France, Germany or Nigeria?

On the bottom line, this policy is just too subjective and segregating if enforced for some movies only and too hard to do and utterly irrelevant if enforced for all movies.

Comment: The Dollars Trilogy is simply an exceptional case. Having a slightly broken policy is better than having no policy at all as you simply lose functionality if you don't. I don't believe that this is subjective; exceptional cases can be handled in meta. IMO, English/Hollywood/whatever simply becomes the default implicit tag for questions which are not about foreign films as the vast majority of questions on this site _are_ about them. We won't have to tag _all_ questions; just the foreign film ones which are currently an insignificant minority.